# Using withTaskCancellationHandler in MainActor-isolated context raises warnings

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

In swift-concurrency, we will get a warning from Xcode when we use `withTaskCancellationHandler` in main-actor-isolated context as the attached screenshot.

How we can solve this warning? in case of using in main-actor context.

[image]

I think I can understand this warning means. Jumping into closure can't guarantee it runs on same context. Which is why closure sometimes needs to have Sendable.
But how about what if the closure is isolated in main-context(using @MainActor)?

I did some experiments - creating mostly same signatured method

```swift
func my_withTaskCancellationHandler<T>(operation: @MainActor () async throws -> T, onCancel handler: @MainActor @Sendable () -> Void) async rethrows -> T {
  fatalError()
}
```

Using Actor attributes is difference.
If we use this method in main-actor context, I suspect it no needs to have sendable. but it does not work as I expected. the same warning's raised.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why does your `static` function need to be actor isolated? It is a `static`, so it obviously is not accessing the state of the actor. I would make it nonisolated and then if you really need to run something on the main actor from inside the `withTaskCancelllationHandler` block, consider `MainActor.run { ... }`.

Comment: Ah, using `static` method is just for making example code. you may imagine this code happening in SwiftUI's view or UIViewController's implementations.

Comment: Maybe show us an example of how you really are going to use this and we can probably provide more precise advice.